# How to show the extensions installed in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I show the versions of the extensions installed in Visual Studio Code?

Also, but unrelated, does anyone know the maximum file size that can be handled by VS Code?

Comment: I do not have the extensions icon in the side bar at all. How do you get that to show, as well, please?

Comment: Just realised I was on a REALLY old version that did not have extensions!

Comment: The minimum maximum file size [is 300MB](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9832#issuecomment-321478890). You may get more, depending on version and architecture.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Hit <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and enter `show i` :

[image]

Click on "Extensions Show Installed Extensions":

[image]

Answer (score 67):

This will work from a command line:

```
code --list-extensions --show-versions
```

I do not know when this functionality was added.  Sample output:

[image: get a list of the installed extensions]

See [CLI Options](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_working-with-extensions)

Comment: To send this to a file in Linux: `echo $(code --list-extensions --show-versions) >> ext.ext`

Comment: That works if you need the output as a single line. To preserve the line breaks between extensions (which I recommend), use `code --list-extensions --show-versions > ext.ext`. Either form can be dropped into a command line with something like `install-my-extensions $(cat ext.ext)`, but the with-line-ends form is easier to process further (possibly at a later time) with tools like `sed` and `awk`.

Comment: This just opens a new VS Code window.

Comment: @gargoylebident It still works for me - I get a list in the terminal, one extension per line, of all the installed extensions.  Seems like it is working for lots of people.  I added a gif to show it working - not sure why you can't get it to work.

Comment: @Mark probably because you have it installed, and I'm using it in portable mode.

Comment: @gargoylebident If you are on Windows, type `code.cmd --list-extensions` instead of just `code`. The problem is `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code` (or vscode install folder) has `code.exe` which opens vscode and is getting called. You actually need to run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd`, which is the command line utility script.

Comment: @gargoylebident If you are on Linux, run the `code` shell script in the `bin` subdirectory of your `vscode` install folder. Both `code.cmd` and `code` (shell script) are in the `bin` subdirectory.

Comment: To send that directly to your clipboard (i.e. auto copy it), pipe it to a copy command. Example (using `pbcopy`): `code --list-extensions --show-versions | pbcopy`

Answer (score 25):

1. Open VS Code.
2. Go to Extensions (in left side-nav or icon with boxes ).
3. In search Extension type: @installed

You will be able to see all installed VS code extensions.

Comment: This was the most useful for me, because it allows searching within installed extensions. Just typing the `@` in the search bar shows an auto-complete of other tag commands as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can access in the right menu like bellow image with shortcut `CTRL+SHIFT+X`.

If does not appear, you can click on three points and then **Show Installed Extensions**.
You can **Uninstall** too in this path.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked well for me. Bonus, you can alphabetize them via `@sort:name`.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click on Extension Icon present in left side panel.
2. It will display the extension list.
3. On top you can see three dots.
4. Click on this dots, it will display the installed extensions