# How to obtain a list of installed VS Code extensions using code

Tags: vscode-extensions

I want to get the list of installed extensions for VS Code *in code*.

**Not from the CLI**, I want it in code so I can write it to the console for diagnostic purposes in the middle of a unit test that's behaving like things aren't installed. It could be that something isn't *yet* loaded (or is loaded but isn't ready yet).

I already know how to get a list from the CLI as detailed here [How to show the extensions installed in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768916).

Probably there's some command I can use with `executeCommand`, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const extensions = vscode.extensions.all;  // returns an array
```

will give you all installed extensions - it does include built-in extensions, like `vscode.xml` and all other pre-installed language extensions.  Not just the extensions you may have manually installed.

You could filter those by their `id` if you wanted.  To remove those starting with `vscode.` for example.

```js
  let extensions = vscode.extensions.all;
  extensions = extensions.filter(extension => !extension.id.startsWith('vscode.'));
```

That'll get rid of ~80 of the built-ins, but there are more - there are a few starting with 'ms-code' you might not be interested in.

Comment: Actually the one that interests me starts with mscode (it's the ssh remote workspace extension). This is a great answer, it's exactly what I wanted.